# Preprocessor concatenation for include path

Tags: c, include, c-preprocessor

I have a set of includes that reside in a far off directory meaning that including them requires a long include, such as:

```
#include "../../Path/to/my/file.h"
```

Where I have multiple of these it becomes a bit inconvenient so I am thinking I may be able to use a #define for the directory path and then concat the file name that I need, i.e.

```
#define DIR "../../Path/to/my/"
#define FILE1 "file.h"
#define FILE2 "anotherFile.h"

#include DIR FILE1 // should end up same as line in first example after pre-proc
```

However this does not work... is there anyway to concatenate within the workings of the C pre-processor suitable for this?

Comment: No, the preprocessor hasn't reflection or meta-programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't customise the search path for include files like this, but you can tell the compiler where to look for include files. Many compilers `-I` option for that, e.g.:

```
gcc -c stuff.c -I/path/to/my/ -I/path/to/other/
```

If that makes your compilation command too long, you should write a Makefile or, if you are working in Visual Studio or similar IDE, customise the search path in your project settings.

Answer (score 6):

The compiler will do macro replacement on an `#include` line (per [C 2011 [N1570] 6.10.2 4](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf#page=182)), but the semantics are not fully defined and cannot be used to concatenate file path components without additional assistance from the C implementation. So about all this allows you to do is some simple substitution that provides a complete path, such as:

```
#define MyPath "../../path/to/my/file.h"
#include MyPath
```

What you can do with most compilers and operating systems is:

- Tell the compiler what directories to search for included files (as with GCC’s `-I` switch).
- Create symbolic links to other directories, so that `#include "FancyStuff/file.h"` becomes equivalent to `../../path/to/FancyStuff` because there is a symbolic link named `FancyStuff` that points to the longer path.