# String concatenation for include path

Tags: c++, c, include, c-preprocessor

Is there a way to concatenate 2 strings literals to form an include path?

Code stub:

```
#define INCLUDE_DIR "/include"
#include INCLUDE_DIR "/dummy.h"
```

Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20524491/preprocessor-concatenation-for-include-path), the answers point in a different direction (compiler command line). It is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20524959/2436175) that it is seemingly not possible, but I wonder if the topic has been dug enough.

(I do have an use case in which this is relevant, please focus your answers/comments on this question only.)

Comment: Are you looking for a solution for a specific compiler or you need a cross-compiler solution? (IMO it's better to add it to the question)

Comment: Tjhere is no such ability in modern C++.

Comment: @mvidelgauz I work with gcc/llvm. I wouldn't add a tag though, compiler specific solutions are in general relevant here, I would say.

Comment: The compiler command line is definitely the way to go here. This configuration belongs in a Makefile (or similar), not inside the code file.

Comment: @KonradRudolph My use case is the following. I have a big project, which uses cmake to generate makefiles/ninja.rules. Within this big project, for semplicity, all include paths are shared. However, depending on same cmake option, an include path *relevant to just a few files* might be excluded or not. If I change one of the cmake option, the include paths change for all files, and therefore ALL files need to be recompiled. The way I solve this, cmake generates a configuration file containing *the full path to the header*, and include this generated file only where that header is necessary.

Comment: @KonradRudolph However, this wouldn't work if I had multiple files to include from that path. I would like cmake only to have to define the include directory, not the full path to the header file.

Comment: I was surprised to see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096201/concatenate-string-in-c-include-filename The answers claim success,  several upvotes and no comments reporting failure. Maybe the practical problem is in the `/` character...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really seems this is not possible. I will report here the relevant section from [Eric Postpischil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20524491/preprocessor-concatenation-for-include-path/20524959#20524959) (he doesn't seem to be active anymore).

> The compiler will do macro replacement on an `#include` line (per C
>   2011 [N1570] 6.10.2 4), but the semantics are not fully defined and
>   cannot be used to concatenate file path components without additional
>   assistance from the C implementation. So about all this allows you to
>   do is some simple substitution that provides a complete path, such as:
>
> ```
> #define MyPath "../../path/to/my/file.h"
> #include MyPath
> ```

[Link to documentation](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf#page=182). In particular this section doesn't leave much hope for portable solutions:

> The  method  by  which  a  sequence  of  preprocessing  tokens between
>   a `<` and a `>` preprocessing token pair or a pair of `"` characters
>   is combined into a single header name preprocessing token is
>   implementation-defined.

---

For completeness, maybe something can be tried using https://stackoverflow.com/a/27830271/2436175. I'll investigate that when I have a moment...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is exactly what you want but anyway.

```
#define DECORATE(x)             <x>
#define MAKE_PATH(root, file)   DECORATE(root file)

#define SYS_DIR(file)           MAKE_PATH(sys/, file)
#define ARPA_DIR(file)          MAKE_PATH(arpa/, file)


#include SYS_DIR(types.h)
#include SYS_DIR(socket.h)
#include ARPA_DIR(inet.h)
```

Note, that generated filenames contain extra space - `<sys/ types.h>`, so it may not be a cross-compiler solution. But at least for me it works on Linux host on GCC 4.8 / 4.9.

P.S. It would be nice if someone could check this snippet with another compilers, e.g. MSVC.

Comment: @AlterMann Really weird behavior, since it builds proper names and expands headers regardless to error messages.

Comment: Do you have a compiler for which this works? I agree one would expect it to do so...

Comment: @Antonio I've removed `##` concatenation, and now it works, but there is a caveat, see my edit.

Comment: To remove space, [concatenation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html) can help.

Comment: @SimpleGuy That's the whole point of this post, it doesn't work for include paths

Comment: This space doesn't sound to be very portable and I could not think about the right search terms to find anything about this (tried `path space after slash`),

Comment: I was surprised to see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096201/concatenate-string-in-c-include-filename The answers claim success,  several upvotes and no comments reporting failure. Maybe the practical problem is in the `/` character...

Comment: The example answer here isn't concatenating string literals like the question has

Answer (score 0):

Simply avoid the space and the concatenation (##) and use the < > it makes all simplier:

```
#include <QtCore/QtGlobal>

#define QT_VERSION_PREFIX QT_VERSION_MAJOR.QT_VERSION_MINOR.QT_VERSION_PATCH

#define _CONCATE(a, c) <a/QT_VERSION_PREFIX/a/private/c>
#include _CONCATE(QtWidgets, qwidgettextcontrol_p.h)
```

Comment: `_CONCATE`?!?!?